# How do you delete a release but not the tag?

Tags: git, github, tags, branch

I'm working through a book. I create a branch for each chapter, after finishing I merge that branch with my `dev` and tag that merge with the finished chapter. I also tag some commits as a solution to the book's challenges.

Once in a while I do some cleaning up of the code, that all happens on my `cleanup` branch. I switch there, merge with `dev`, do the cleanup, merge `dev`, tag that merge as a cleanup.

```
*   004dce5 (HEAD -> dev, tag: CLEANUP, origin/dev) COSMETIC: add dividers to classes
|\  
| * 9d2a352 (origin/cleanup, cleanup) Divide class sections
|/  
*   c10ba19 (tag: chap_14) User can add crime
|\  
| * c1dfd26 (origin/done/core/app_bar) Appbar adds crime
| * 2b9e540 Ability to add crimes to DB
| * 3171aec Create the menu item for adding crimes
| * ea78e97 Create an app bar layout
|/  
| *   951310d (origin/master, master) App allows to modify date & time
| |\  
| |/  
|/|   
* |   122b109 (tag: chall_13) User can modify time
|\ \  
| * | 947cb25 (origin/done/ftr/time_dialog) Connect TimePickerFragment
| * | 6f3a94b Add companion functions
| * | 4ad2df6 Change HOUR to HOUR_OF_DAY
| * | c68c7d0 Create and implement TimePickerFragment
| * | 863bc03 Create Time class
|/ /  
* |   d317099 (tag: chap_13) User can modify date
|\ \  
| * | 6257d7e (origin/done/core/dialog) Date selected gets stored
| * | cf82692 Date button opens calendar at correct date
| * | 7c68abb Date button opens calendar
| * | 409afff Create DatePickerFragment
|/ /  
| *   dc33ac0 Efficiency improvements
| |\  
| |/  
|/|   
* |   d5dcd80 (tag: chall_12) Improve efficiency of CrimeListFragment
|\ \  
| * | c84f6e6 (origin/done/impr/list_adapter) Use ListAdapter instead of Adapter
| * | 840bdad Implement equals()
|/ /  
| *   aa2ea46 App can display individual crimes
| |\  
| |/  
|/|   
* |   63b768d (tag: chap_12) Allow users to modify crimes
|\ \  
| * | 087c989 (origin/done/core/updating_db) User modifications in CrimeFragment are saved
| * | b940a6a CrimeViewModel: implement saveCrime()
| * | 6704665 Implement listeners to titleField and dateButton
| * | 48457d9 Add updateCrime() functionality
|/ /  
* |   1c368a1 Clicking on a crime opens details
```

Github considers each tag as a release, which I don't want.

How do I delete the releases without also deleting the tags?

Is there a better way to do things I just decribed?

Comment: https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/editing-and-deleting-releases#deleting-a-release

Comment: @jonrsharpe that will delete the tag as well...

Answer (score 1):

According to [the GitHub blog announcement of releases](https://github.blog/2013-07-02-release-your-software/), a GitHub release is intimately tied to a Git tag:

> Following the conventions of many Git projects, releases are tied to Git tags.
>   You can use an existing tag, or let releases create the tag when it’s published.

However, the existence of a tag doesn't imply the existence of a release.  Logically, then, if deleting a release causes GitHub to delete the tag, the way to handle this would be to tell GitHub to delete the release—which deletes *their copy* of the tag—then use `git push` from your own clone, where you have retained the tag, to re-create the *tag* without re-creating the *release* as well.

(This all assumes you have your own clone of your own repository, rather than trying to do everything directly *on* GitHub itself.)